# Vue + Laravel SPA project - How can I hide login and register router-links in navbar right after login?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, navigation, vue-router

I am making a project for my Bachelor's degree and I am having an issue. While the login, register and logout all work fine, the page wont automatically switch between login/register and logout in the navbar.
The navbar component:

```
<template>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <router-link to="/" class="routerLink"><h1>Proiect Licenta</h1></router-link>

                <div class="menu">
                    <router-link to="/buy">Buy Crypto</router-link>
                    <router-link to="/market">Market</router-link>
                    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
                    <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link>
                    <router-link v-if="!checkLogged" to="/signup">Signup</router-link>
                    <router-link v-if="!checkLogged" to="/login">Login</router-link>
                    <base-button mode="flat" v-if="checkLogged" @click="logout">Logout</base-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</template>

<script>
import User from '../../helpers/User.js';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    methods: {
        logout() {
            User.logOut()

            Toast.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Logout successfully'
            });

            this.$router.push({ name: 'homePage' });
        },
    },
    computed: {
        checkLogged() {
            if(User.loggedIn()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
    },
}
</script>

User.js:

    hasToken() {
        const storeToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

        if(storeToken) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    loggedIn() {
        return this.hasToken();
    }

    logOut() {
       localStorage.removeItem('token');
       localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }
```

The navbar is imported in the app.vue component so I pressume it always stays there and nothing changes about it until I refresh the page. How can I immediately switch between these 2 router-links and the logout one right after login and redirectioning to the main page? If you need any other details I will reply fast. Thank you.

Comment: I think posting the code of ```User.js``` file could help you get better answers.

Comment: I updated the code with the user.js part

Comment: Does it work when you refresh the page? I mean for example if you click on **logout** button and then refresh the page does the **Signup** and **Login** links appears or not?

Comment: Yes. The code for signing in, loggin in or logging out work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

As your code is about user login and logout and maybe there are some codes related to the back-end part of your app that do the **login-logout** process, I tried to simulate the process with clicking **login** and **logout** buttons. I mean that by clicking that buttons I called the functions from `user.js` file and ignore the process of login or register. here is the code of `"user.js"`:

> `user.js`:

```js
export default {
    hasToken() {
        const storeToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

        if (storeToken) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },

    loggedIn() {
        return this.hasToken();
    },

    logOut() {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
    },

    /* I created this method to simulate the login of user. maybe you set "token" in other parts of your code. */
    login() {
        console.log("logged in");
        localStorage.setItem("token", "my value");
    }
}
```

And here is the code of navigation that you could import in `App.vue`.

> `TheNavigation.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="container">
        <router-link to="/" class="routerLink"><h1>Proiect Licenta</h1></router-link>

        <div class="menu">
          <router-link to="/buy">Buy Crypto</router-link>
          <router-link to="/market">Market</router-link>
          <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
          <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link>
          <router-link v-if="!switchData" to="/signup">Signup</router-link>
          <router-link @click.native="loginMethod" v-if="!switchData" to="/login">Login</router-link>
          <button mode="flat" v-if="switchData" @click="logout">Logout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
/* import user.js from your own address */
import User from '../helper/user.js';

export default {
  name: "TheNavigation",
  data() {
    return {
      switchData: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logout() {
      User.logOut()
      /* you should call "checkLogged" method after logout or login or signup to check the state of "local-storage" each time */
      this.checkLogged();

    },
    checkLogged() {
      /* instead of returning "true" or "false", change the value of "switchData" to benefit from Vue "reactivity"  */
      if(User.loggedIn()) {
        this.switchData = true;
      } else {
        this.switchData = false;
      }
    },
    loginMethod() {
      User.login();
      /* you should call "checkLogged" method after logout or login or signup to check the state of "local-storage" each time */
      this.checkLogged();
    }
  }
  // computed: {
  //   checkLogged() {
  //     if(User.loggedIn()) {
  //       return true;
  //     }
  //     return false;
  //   },
  // }
}
</script>
```

The main change in my approach from what you did is that I converted `checkLogged()` from a **computed property** to a **Vue method** and call it after **login** or **logout**. So Vue can check the local-storage each time and switch the buttons and links accordingly. Also you can test it in this [code sand-box](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-fire-4u7nij?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: I think that I will need to learn Vuex in order to make it work as intended in different components unrelated to each other. The switchData variable needs to be global in order for this to work, but thank you. You get me some good ideas. I will try on the model.

Comment: @The_Goose I also added a link of code-sand-box at the end of my answer that you could test it online.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort as your example inspired me. In the end I figured out how to make Vuex work and I did it through it,